# PHP deleting from database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to let the user check off which item to be deleted. When the user check off one or many items and click the Delete button, those data will be erased from the database. I've also added a search box to search for the dvd. The search box works, but the deleting doesn't. This is what it looks like in the browser.

[image: PHP deleting]

My PHP looks like this (I took out the searching code):

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="search"> <input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="deleting" value="Delete"></p>
</form>
<?php   
    $link = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully<br/>';

//searching code goes here 

if (isset ($_POST['deleting']) && isset ($_POST['deleteThese']) )
{
$deleteThese = implode(",", $_POST['deleteThese']); 
$queryTwo = "DELETE FROM `$dbname`.`dvds` WHERE `dvds`.`DvdID` IN ($deleteThese)"; 
$resultTwo = mysqli_query($link, $queryTwo);
}

echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>DvdTitle</th><th>RunningTime</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
   echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>No records found.</td></tr>";

   else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['DvdTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['RunningTime'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<form>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='deleteThese[]' value='" . $row['DvdID'] . "' >" . "</form>" . "</td></tr>\n"; 
           }
        }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Each DvdTitle has an unique Dvd ID, hence the value of each row is the dvd's ID `$row['DvdID']`.

Comment: You get no errors (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`)?

Comment: nope, there were no error

Comment: print_r($queryTwo);die(); //copy paste it and run manually in phpMyAdmin or whatever :)

Comment: @FeRtoll where do you run that code? in the SQL query of phpMyAdmin? I'm using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the parentheses will allow for those ID's to be selected  for deletion.

```
 IN($deleteThese)
```

**EDIT**

Do not close the form after the submit button. Put that at the end of the code. This will allow the form to include the checkbox values.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="search"> <input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
<!-- YOUR PHP CODE -->
<p><input type="submit" name="deleting" value="Delete"></p>
</form>
```

**2nd Edit [requested to improve code]**

Move the isset on top of the form.

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['deleting']) && isset ($_POST['deleteThese']) )
{
  $deleteThese = implode(",", $_POST['deleteThese']); 
  $queryTwo = "DELETE FROM `$dbname`.`dvds` WHERE `dvds`.`DvdID` IN ($deleteThese)"; 
  $resultTwo = mysqli_query($link, $queryTwo);
}
?>
<form>....
```

Comment: like this? `"<form>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='deleteThese[]' value='" . $row['DvdID'] . "' >" . "</form>"`

Comment: It's working, sort of. When I checkoff an item and click delete, nothing happens. But if I refresh the page, then it will delete the item. How do I fix that?

Comment: move the whole isset($_POST['deleting']) block outside the form. I edited the code of how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

`$deletethese` might need to have quotes around it.